# Where do I attach the StoreKit delegate and observer in a Cocos2d App?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have figured out how all of the StoreKit stuff works and have actually tested working code... however, I have a problem.

I made my "store" layer/scene the `SKProductsRequestDelegate`.  Is this the correct thing to do?  I get the initial product info like so:

```
SKProductsRequest *productRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: productIDs];

[productRequest setDelegate: self];
[productRequest start];
```

The problem is that if I transition to a new scene when a request is in progress, the current layer is retained by the productRequest.  This means that touches on my new scene/layer are handled by both the new layer and the old layer.

I could cancel the productRequest when leaving the scene, but:

1. I do not know if it is in progress at that point.
2. I cannot release it because it may or may not have been released by the request delegates.

There has got to be a better way to do this.  I could make the delegate a class external to the current layer, but then I do not know how to easily update the layer with the product information when the handler is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, problem solved.... ergh.

1. I went ahead and made the store a separate class, and solved the issue of callbacks to the scene by adding a delegate to the class, which holds the layer of the Store interface.  When the transactions finish, I can use the delegate to call back to my scene/layer.
2. I solved the issue of not knowing if the delegate has been released by using the `respondsToSelector:` method before attempting to send a message to it.
3. It turns out the real bug was caused by my attempt to fix 1 & 2 in the first place.  I overrode `onExit` to let me know when to remove the class as the store delegate.  It turns out I forgot to call `[super onExit]`, which is where the scene is released.  Hence, it stayed retained and did not get removed from the touchHandler.  Oops!